# Fitting a UIImagePicker inside a navigation controler?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm making an application that uses the iphone camera to detect the changing brightness of the video stream. The video feed should be mid-way through a trail of views under the navigation controller. On pressing a button on this view, the user should see a view that displays the average brightness of the video stream.

I am having quite a lot of trouble getting the UIImagePicker to display in the right way. I've found that it is not possible to output it to a nested UIView - instead, the overlay for the camera should be set to display any extra functionality. I need this overlay to be part of my navigation controller.

I have the following code inside `LuxMeterController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.tst != YES) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
        picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        LuxMeterController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cameraVc"];
        vc.tst = YES;

        picker.cameraOverlayView = vc.view;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
    }
}
```

So first, the view is loaded - it initializes the camera and displays it as a modal view. The overlay of the camera is set to a second instance of `LuxViewController` - this one doesn't render a new camera as `tst == YES`.

This sort of seems to work - I have a video feed with a full-screen view as its overlay.

My problem is that as the overlay is not part of the hierarchy in the storyboard, it doesn't have UI elements (titlebar, back button,etc) that come from the navigation controller.

How do I get the overlay to sit inside the navigation controller? Or is this the wrong approach to take? How can I get a videostream to sit inside the navigation controller hierarchy, and to have overlay buttons that can move to a view further down the hierarchy?

I've only been doing objective-c and iphone development for a very short period of time, so I might be missing something obvious. If there is a better approach, I'd like to know about it.